# No. of up-votes went missing in four hours

Tags: support, up-votes

The no. of up-votes this afternoon in my account was exact 354. Yesterday it was 329.

But later, this evening, I checked out my account to find out that the no. of up-votes went down, and now they're 315.

How did this happen?

Comment: In addition to what Jon said, it's possible that you voted for too many of a single user's posts -- or a small group of users' posts -- in a short period of time. But everything is speculation unless/until you can get a mod to spend some time looking at your personal voting history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but this could happen if questions/answers you voted on were deleted or migrated.

Popular Demand's comment offers another possibility:

> ...it's possible that you voted for too many of a single user's posts -- or a small group of users' posts -- in a short period of time.